# Trying to download image from tumblr using java selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to download images form tumblr using java selenium. I extracted the url of the image from src and tried to download images from url. But the images saved not what I expected. Those are in unsupported formats and smaller in size. How can I correct this? Please help.

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException, IOException {

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://artist-childe-hassam.tumblr.com/");
    Thread.sleep(5000); 
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_END);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_END);

    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@alt]"));
    int count;
    count = 1;
    for (WebElement element : list) {

        String srcs = element.getAttribute("src");
        String attribute = element.getAttribute("alt");
        System.out.println("title: " + attribute);
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("link " + srcs);
    
        URL url = new URL(srcs);
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n = 0;
        while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
        {
           out.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
        
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("path"+count+".jpg");
        count++;
        fos.write(response);
        fos.close();
        }

    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have idea on BufferedInputStream to download image from URL. Instead, I used to use curl to download from URL. I have modified your code and its working fine for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException, IOException {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://artist-childe-hassam.tumblr.com/");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_END);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_END);

        List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@alt]"));
        int count;
        count = 1;
        for (WebElement element : list) {
            String srcs = element.getAttribute("src");
            String attribute = element.getAttribute("alt");
            System.out.println("title: " + attribute);
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("link " + srcs);

            downloadFromUrl(srcs,"Path" + count+".jpg",Duration.ofSeconds(20));
            count++;
        }

    }

    public static boolean downloadFromUrl(String url, String fileNameWithPath, Duration timeoutDuration) {
        try {
            if(timeoutDuration == null) {
                timeoutDuration = Duration.ofMinutes(5);
            }
            String curlStr = "curl " + url + " --output " + fileNameWithPath;
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(curlStr);
            long totalSeconds = 0;
            System.out.println("Downloading file to " + fileNameWithPath + " ...");
            while(process.isAlive()) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                totalSeconds++;
                if(totalSeconds > timeoutDuration.getSeconds()) {
                    throw new Exception("Unable to download file even after 5 mins of wait");
                }
            }
            System.out.println(fileNameWithPath + " got downloaded in seconds - " + totalSeconds);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

My downloaded images:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you please explain what 'public static boolean downloadFromUrl' actually is? I'm fairly new so I don't understand this part of the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In order to download image from url, am using "curl" method. In this case, we need to build the curl statement and trigger it. That will automatically download the file to the specified location. This is just like running curl statements in terminal.